# error : BOOST DISABLE THREADS

Tags: c++, boost, freebsd

i have some problem with my boost library. i m using freebsd and installed my boost using ports. Boost version is : 1.45 and i use g++47 as compiler. Also i have never defined BOOST DISABLE THREADS  at there : /usr/local/include/boost/config/user.hpp .Also exactly my error is :

```
 /usr/local/include/boost/config/requires_threads.hpp:29:4: error: #error "Threading    support unavaliable: it has been explicitly disabled with BOOST_DISABLE_THREADS"
```

explicitly but where ?? And my compile command;

```
 g++47 -O3 -Wall -std=c++0x   -I. -Iinclude -I../include -I/usr/local/include   -c -o     Application.o src/Application.cpp
```

Thanks

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The experimental GCC version 4.7 disables Boost.Threads. See: https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/6165

**Edit:** It should be noted that as of the release version of GCC 4.7, and Boost higher than 1.48 (Boost_1_48_0 is still not working), threads works again.

Comment: GCC doesn't "disable" anything, Boost.Threads 1.47 failed to correctly detect thread support in the compiler, because the undocumented implementation detail that Boost relied on changed. This is also nothing to do with experimental vs release versions, the same applies to all versions of 4.7

Comment: Interesting, I have this same problem with gcc 4.8.1 and boost 1.55 - is there any solution other than backing up to 4.7?

Comment: GCC 4.8.1 + Boost 1_47 same error.
Apparently it's boost using an undocumented feature to detect something, that no longer works on later GCC versions...?

Comment: Just upgraded Boost. GCC 4.8.1 + Boost 1_55, again same error.

Comment: @Mike: See the ticket 6165 mentioned above by Joachim:

To define 'threads' support, GCC <= 4.6 defines '_GLIBCXX__PTHREADS', whereas GCC >= 4.7 defines '_GLIBCXX_HAS_GTHREADS'.

So, in order to compile older Boosts using any GCC more recent than 4.6 you need the patch libstdcpp3.hpp.patch enclosed in that ticket.

URL: https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/attachment/ticket/6165/libstdcpp3.hpp.patch

Answer (score 9):

See the ticket [6165](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/6165) mentioned above by Joachim:
To define 'threads' support,

- GCC <= 4.6 defines `_GLIBCXX__PTHREADS`
- whereas GCC >= 4.7 defines `_GLIBCXX_HAS_GTHREADS`.

So, in order to compile older Boosts using any GCC more recent than 4.6 you need the patch [libstdcpp3.hpp.patch](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/attachment/ticket/6165/libstdcpp3.hpp.patch) enclosed in that ticket.

Another problem that could also prevent Boost on working with modern compiler is ticket [6940](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/6940) (`TIME_UTC` has a special meanhing in C11, therefore Boost >= 1.50 use `TIME_UTC_` instead)

Comment: This is such a helpful answer, saved me a ton of time, thanks!