# decltype for map value type?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11

Is this legal in c++11:

```
std::unordered_map<X, Y> xy_map;
X my_x;
Y my_y;
xy_map.insert(decltype(xy_map)::value_type(my_x, my_y));
```

I tried this in gcc 4.6.3 and it did not work. GCC complains:

```
expected primary-expression before 'decltype'
```

I was hoping not to do:

```
typedef std::unordered_map<X, Y> MyMap;
xy_map.insert(MyMap::value_type(my_x, my_y));
```

I guess c++11 doesn't solve that or make it any easier.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I can't use gcc 4.7 cause they broke some other stuff in there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8297652/error-boost-disable-threads :(

Comment: You may be already aware of it but the usual way is to use `std::make_pair(my_x, my_y)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code is correct C++. Like Basile alluded to in a comment, this was a bug that was fixed for GCC 4.7.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't answer your question, but it does have the virtue of likely working on your compiler:

```
xy_map.emplace(my_x, my_y);
```

[That will construct the value type from the given arguments.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/emplace) The first argument constructs the key, and the others are used for the value. This will effectively construct the `std::pair` in place. So no need for ugly things like `decltype` and such.

Comment: emplace would be great, but it doesn't work on gcc 4.6.3 either. :(