# CMake can not find Boost library

Tags: boost, cmake

I am trying to build C++ project which uses Boost and CMake as a build system. In CMakeLists.txt there are following standard lines:

```
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS serialization date_time)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
set(LIBS ${LIBS} ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

I have installed Boost from repository (Fedora 16 in my case) and CMake can not find it (Boost_DIR-NOT_FOUND).

I have looked through similar issues in internet and could not find appropriate solution that will work in my case. In some cases there were advices to use separate Boost install from sources but I would not like to do it as it will take a lot of time to compile since I use VirtualBox.

Could anybody help me with this issue?

Best regards,

Alex

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17568019/where-is-the-directory-containing-a-cmake-configuration-file-for-boost/17568696#17568696

Comment: @ComicSansMS Yeah, funny, it was asked just yesterday :)

Comment: Thank you, ComicSansMS! Your reference really helped.