# Linux Ubuntu 14.04, boost libs and thread compilations

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, ubuntu, boost

I have a program I want to compile under linux ubuntu.
But though I have already installed `libboost-all-dev`, it still throws me some errors.
Errors are too many to post just here, I better include a pastebin instead: http://pastebin.com/vjeMbjGa

They are mostly connected with libboost-thread, as far as I've got it. But I don't know:

1. Where to turn on the `BOOST_DISABLE_THREADS` constant and why is it turned off by default?
2. Is error `"Sorry, no boost threads are available for this platform."` dependant on `BOOST_DISABLE_THREADS`? I do not believe that Ubuntu 14.04 do not support threading.
3. As far as I know, `TIME_UTC` was changed in some version of C. How to fix it up for Boost?

Any other explanations are appreciated too.
Thank you all who help.

Comment: is this of any help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8297652/error-boost-disable-threads

Comment: Your errors indicates boost is installed under /usr/local/  - that's not from the Ubuntu boost packages, so perhaps you've installed boost yourself - but configured it without threading support ?

Comment: @nos, Well, I have tried to install boost 1.54 by myself. But i think there were no errors.

Comment: @Duosora I think you disabled threading support when you did so, and the code you're trying to compile now is using that boost installation, instead of the one you've installed with the libboost-all-dev package. So remove the boost stuff under /usr/local.

Comment: @nos I have removed boost folder from /usr/local/include. It resulted more errors like `error: ‘class boost::filesystem::directory_entry’ has no member named ‘filename’`. What to do with it?

Comment: @Duosora I can't see in the boost documentation that boost::filesystem::directory_entry has a filename member, so something's wrong with the code you wrote. Create a new question where you show your code, preferably a complete example that shows the issue you have.

Answer (score 0):

```
wiesniak@wiesniak-Precision-M4800:~$ apt-cache search boost-thread
libboost-thread-dev - portable C++ multi-threading (default version)
libboost-thread1.54-dev - portable C++ multi-threading
libboost-thread1.54.0 - portable C++ multi-threading
libboost-thread1.55-dev - portable C++ multi-threading
libboost-thread1.55.0 - portable C++ multi-threading
wiesniak@wiesniak-Precision-M4800:~$
```

install this package by:
sudo apt-get install libboost-thread-dev